# Upload Csv to Analytics Management API( Unknown filename)

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I was trying to upload CSV file to Google Analytics using Management API, but I get Unknown filename under Manage uploads Tab ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN6mr.png)). Refering to this post [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702745/how-to-upload-cost-to-google-analytics-using-google-spreadsheet), I've been using the same code. Also tried [REST API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-js) but I got the same issue.

Maybe someone who had solved the issue to give a helping hand ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a known issue based from [Issue 791](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=791) in   analytics-issues tracker. Given workaround is that:

> CURL can be used to upload a file and the filename remains in the POST body and it will be preserved in the UI.

As also given, you may use the following sample CURL parameter and request body:

> `curl -X POST -F "upload=@YOURFILENAME.csv;type=application/octet-stream" "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/v3/management/accounts/XXXXXX/webproperties/UA-XXXXXX-1/customDataSources/CUSTOMDATASOURCEID/uploads?access_token=ya29.REPLACEWIHTYOURVALIDTOKEN" -v`

Furthermore, you may also check [Uploads: uploadData](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData) for more information.